# Removing rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma) requirement

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, opensuse

I'm building RPMs on my OpenSUSE 11.2 machine and uploading them to a CentOS 5 server. When trying to install, I get messages similar to:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma) <= 4.4.6-1 is needed by xxx.rpm
```

How can I fix this? Removing the LZMA compression for the RPMs when building is preferred, but I'd also work with installing an extra package on the CentOS server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer here: http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-March/035580.html

Looks like you need to modify the RPM spec file to include: _binary_payload w9.gzdio

Comment: Thanks! My problem is long gone through other means but it's good to know.